# Clicking on android back button should show the last View. Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

Here what I want is when we click on the android back button it should show the previous view(i.e Image View) instead of closing the application.  Please help me out. Been stuck here.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor : "#ffffff",
        modal: true,
        navBarHidden: true,
        fullscreen: true
    });
    win.open();

var view1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: M16.ImageURLs.SELECT_SHARE,
    width:Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL  
});

var view2 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: M16.ImageURLs.YOUR_SHARE,
    width:Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL  
});

var view3 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: M16.ImageURLs.FRIENDS_APPLY,
    width:Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL  
});

var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height:Ti.UI.FILL,
    showPagingControl:false,
    pagingControlTimeout:0,
    views:[view1,view2,view3]
    });
win.add(scrollableView);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Back button exits application in android using appcelerator titanium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544402/back-button-exits-application-in-android-using-appcelerator-titanium)

Comment: Take a look at answers under this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544402/back-button-exits-application-in-android-using-appcelerator-titanium

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
win.addEventListener('androidback', navigateToPreviousView);

function navigateToPreviousView(){
   var currentPage = scrollableView.currentPage; //Getting the current index
   if(currentPage > 0){     //Checking whether the current page is first page
      scrollableView.movePrevious();   //navigating to the previous view

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after your code.

```
var previousPage = scrollableView.currentPage;
var currentPage = previousPage;
scrollableView.addEventListener('scrollend', function (e) {
    previousPage = currentPage;
    currentPage = scrollableView.currentPage;
});

win.addEventListener('androidback', function (e) {
    scrollableView.setCurrentPage(previousPage);
});
```

I tried it and it works fine :)